# How to save inputs wihtout html tags in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

The problem is after inserting into the database, the html tags like p,h2 etc. is there together with the user's input.

I tried the php function mysqli_real_escape_string but it doesn't work. The html tags are still in the db.

```
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<?php 
include 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['msg']);
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO messages(msg) VALUES('$msg')");
}
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea name="msg" id="editor">   </textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#editor',
  auto_focus: 'element1',
  width: "200",
  height: "200"
});
</script>
```

I want is after saving the inputs there is no html tags in the database.

Comment: [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) ? ... though, why implement TinyMCE (a *WYSIWYG* editor) if you don't want HTML in the system (there's nothing inherently wrong with having HTML in the database btw)? You should also look at [prepared statements with bound parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: It might be a good addition to keep the breaks `str_replace("<br>", "\n", $_POST['msg'])` before calling `strip_tags()`

Answer (score 3):

Use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
<?php

$msg = strip_tags($msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the html tags, you can use `strip_tags()`.

```
$_POST['msg'] = strip_tags($_POST['msg']);
```